# Build Pagination in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, pagination

I've tried a lot but didn't get an exact  solution for My problem I want to build a pagination look like this

[image]
But I didn't get the logic of  the above pagination

Suppose I've

```
var totalItems  = 100;
var perPage     =10
```

How can I build a pagination that satisfies the above pagination

**Basic HTML for Pagination(W3C SCHOOLS)**

```
<div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a class="active" href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <a href="#">5</a>
  <a href="#">6</a>
  <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
</div>

.pagination a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
}

.pagination a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}
```

Found one [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzp0dw83) but, its too basic.

**UPDATE**

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkk6w8b3/)

Comment: `i didn't get the logic of the above pagination` - the logic is, display page numbers, highlight current page, replace long sequences of page numbers with `..` - pretty simple

Comment: Show us a code example of what you have tried.

Comment: @JaromandaX can you little more specific??

Comment: logically I've described the logic, so, no

Comment: @user340764 my code sample  is pretty simple

Comment: What have you really tried ?

Comment: @Weedoze let me update my code

Comment: Have you try to do this using bootstrap?

Comment: i just want the logic not the bootstrap paginator UI

Comment: $(function() {
    $(selector).pagination({
        items: 100,
        itemsOnPage: 10,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme'
    });
});
Have seen this?

Comment: @NarendraSolanki - jQuery not asked for

Comment: basic one http://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/tb91m3t0/1/

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the fiddle

Comment: @Jabaa - that sounds so wrong :p the fiddle has basic logic, no links or stuff are created, I leave that to you :p

Comment: @JaromandaX what do you meant by so wrong??

Comment: *"thanks for the fiddle"* sounds "rude" - nevermind about that remark

Comment: that didn't mean rude actually i get an entry point to the solution from your fiddle thats really a thanks not a rude:)

Comment: @JaromandaX i got a solution from a  PHP script but its really hard to understand the logic https://docs.google.com/document/d/10WsFA2KXar8Sn3vqRrZykurqqGs2bjyZkP0UMXNFn68/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you doing it using AJAX? because If you don't, I guess you don't even need JS for this

Comment: Yes i am doing it with ajax

Comment: You can try the solution of @JaromandaX - I tried it and it seems really good (and since you're using ajax this can solve your problem. PHP solution seems to be unnecessary)

Comment: @natanel97 next and prev page logic is not present in his answer

Comment: @Jabaa - well, your pretty picture doesn't even show prev page, so ... I didn't realise you needed all the code written for you. I mean, the code I presented doesn't even react to clicks, so, it's just the logic of the pagination